# My program keeps getting an error called 'inconsistent use of tabs and spaces' when I add an else or elif statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, github

My code goes as follows

```
if (input("").lower() == "yes"):
    gender_set()
elif name.lower()=="dev mode":
            print("dev mode activated")
            gender_set()
    else:
    name_set()
```

my file is at 
https://github.com/GamingTimelord19/first-project/commit/0f5639e689a0824580bf5135ecbf8a0c12abf445#diff-9f9a01b179db586487b21757ae29e719L29

Comment: Did you even read the error message?

Comment: You're using tabs and spaces inconsistently.  Pick one and don't use the other.  (p.s. official style guide PEP 8 says use spaces exclusively)  http://pep8.org/

Comment: What entity gives you that error message? Is it from an IDE of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an indentation problem :

```
if (input("").lower() == "yes"):
    gender_set()
elif name.lower()=="dev mode":
    print("dev mode activated")
    gender_set()
else:
    name_set()
```